# Opening main activity after ending second activity

Tags: android, android-activity, push-notification, android-service

i hope someone can help me with this.
I'm opening an activity "B" through a Notification Push using a pending intent. This is working correctly. But I need that when activity B is closed go to my main activity A. When I tap in back button my app is completely closed because the only activity open is B.

How can i do that?

I have read that one way is that in my Service I need to start activity A with some extras in the intent and then in activity A check for these extras to redirect to activity B. But I don't want that. I need to open activity B directly and when it is finished go to main activity A.

Also I know i can use onDestroy method from activity B to start my activity A, but these won't work when i have more activities, i'll need to do the same in every activity

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TaskStackBuilder

Comment: Use `TaskStackBuilder` to construct a task stack that includes both A and B.

Answer (score 0):

There is more than a way to solve this. The easiest one is probably to override the onBackPressed method, start the ActivityA and finish the ActivityB.
Something like this:

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
        navigateTo<ActivityA>()
        finish()
    }
```

Of course, this would happen every time you back pressed from ActivityB, not only when you start it with the notification. Not sure if that is the behavior you expect.

Comment: No, i dont want to use onBackPressed because if i have more activities i will need to override every onBackPressed method